# Error when upgrading to 2.10.1 - Site not working

Tags: upgrade

My site, which was running 2.9.x, was delivering a blank page today. In the past, I've found that getting the current version was the first step to debugging.

So, I decided to start by upgrading to the current version of EE.  After following the directions and clicking on the Upgrade button, I received the following error:

```
Error Number: 1

Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_26a4_0.MYI' (Errcode: 30)

SHOW COLUMNS FROM `exp_sessions`

Filename: /home/bp/public_html/ee_cms/expressionengine/libraries/Smartforge.php

Line Number: 122
```

Oh, crap. Please help.

Comment: error code 30 means that file system is read only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a weird disk corruption issue, here ya go homie:

http://thecancerus.com/how-to-fix-mysql-error-error-code-30/

You need control of your server for this fix. If you have control, back things up and go for it, if not, you should nicely ask your hosting partner to look into this issue.

Comment: Thank you!  That did the trick. Based on this suggestion and some Googling, I took the problem to my hosting provider and they fixed the /tmp file system.

Comment: No prob, chief. Glad you got it sorted out!